# Продление времени жизни временного объекта при возврате из функции

Tags: c++

Будет ли корректен такой код:

```
A Foo ()
{
  A a;
  return a;
}

int main ()
{
  const A &a = Foo ();
  //some work with a
  return 0;
}
```

Я всегда считал, что будет, но тут возникло сомнение, объект создан в функции, что произойдёт при его возврате ? Возможно, при выходе из функции вызовутся деструкторы и `A a` умрёт, а продление жизни возникает лишь при более простой инициализации:

```
const A &a = A ();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Я всегда считал, что будет, но тут возникло сомнение, объект создан в функции, что произойдёт при его возврате ?

Вы смешали два случая, которые практически не имеют отношения друг к другу. Первое - константная ссылка продляет время жизни временного объекта, точка. То есть:

```
A foo();

int main()
{
    const A &a = foo();
}
```

это валидный код вне зависимости от того, что там происходит внутри `foo()`

Второй случай, что происходит в коде:

```
A foo()
{
    A a;
    return a;
}
```

Это зависит от некоторых параметров, которые к данному вопросу не имеют отношения. В любом случае либо сам объект `a` либо его копия будут возвращены в виде временного объекта. На валидность кода это не влияет.

Answer (score 1):

Работать будет.
Но здесь возможно 2 варианта:

1. Если сработает оптимизация (должна сработать начиная с С++ 17) то будет создание 1 объекта и возврат его из функции. Есть там правда некоторые ограничения. Это называется Return Value Optimization (RVO). статья [RVO/NRVO](https://habr.com/ru/company/vk/blog/666330/)
2. Если оптимизации не будет, то вернется копия объекта. Т.е. будет создан объект, создан второй объект через конструктор копирования, первый объект уничтожен, второй объект вернут из функции.

Comment: То есть, по стандарту тут никакого UB нету ? Продление жизни временной переменной сработает? (PS минусанул не я)

Comment: (1) C++17 не гарантирует NRVO, только RVO. (2) Будет перемещение, не копирование.